# HTML markup does not change when the UI changes in isomorphic react web app

Tags: reactjs, ejs, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering

I am using react for creating a sample page which has server side rendering using **renderToString()** for SEO friendly pages.

this is my server.js code

```js
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
    (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
      // in case of error display the error message
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }
      // generate the React markup for the current route
      let markup;
      if (renderProps) {
        markup = renderToString(<RouterContext{...renderProps}/>);
      } else { 
        res.status(404);
      }
      // render the index template with the embedded React markup
      return res.render('index', { markup });
    }
  );
});
```

My page is search page which is static initially and when the user enters the input it fetches data from backend and renders a list of components in the same page.

When I see view page source in browser, I can see only the initial static content, not the html of list which renders after the backend response.

What is the right method to get the updated HTML when the component state changes.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to include your component, and React itself, on your clientside and call `React.render` on the same base element in the DOM.

Simply serving the result of `React.renderToString` as static HTML does will only do exactly that, serve **static** html.

If you want your component to get mounted properly on the clientside so it can react to clientside events and re-render for state changes, you'll need to mount it on the static html, this is done by calling `React.render` on page load on the clientside.

There's more about this here: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-react-isomorphic-javascript-why-it-matters/

Comment: my component is getting mounted properly on client side and very well responding to all events and actions. And client even re-renders on state change. BUT the HTML markup remains the same when I use "view page source" of the browser. And I want the updated html for SEO purpose. My functional requirements are fully functioning.

Comment: Well of course it will, unless you are updating that state to the server somehow it has no knowledge of it when rendering to string

Comment: How will I update the state in the server side from component ?

Comment: I am not using redux store and anything else. because my app is simple with  few data.

Answer (score -1):

Save the fetched data to your state and the component will re-render itself. That way your view will render the new content when it's fetched from the backend.

Comment: i know that the component will get rendered when the state changes. But my issues is that, html markup does not change.

Comment: What do you want to render with your new data. A list of results from the search string? Or that's not the problem?

Comment: Yes. A list of results . it is getting rendered . There is no issues in rendering. My problem is in view page source , when you check the html content, new elements are not added which i want for SEO purpose. Please have a look at server side rendering in react for SEO